# vim bundles are not installed by vundle exactly in Puppet

Tags: git, vim, puppet

I am trying to puppetise vundle which is to be used for CentOS user. 
The result of Puppet is positive without any error messages:

> notice: /Stage[main]/Devops-base-utilities::Vimconfig   /Exec[install_vundle]/returns: executed successfully

But when I checked `~/.vim/bundle` directory, only vundle was cloned from git repository.

The exec command module is below:

```
exec { "install_vundle":
  user        => www,
  command     => 'vim +BundleInstall +qall',
  path        => "/usr/bin",
  provider    => shell,
  refreshonly => true,
  require     => [Package["vim-enhanced"], Exec["clone_vundle"]],
  subscribe   => File['/home/www/.vimrc.bundles.local']
}
```

But `vim +BundleInstall +qall` can be launched manually.

Comment: Vundle's issue tracker is [that way](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle/issues).

Comment: It is not an issue of vundle, but just asking for a proper way to automate installation using Puppet.

Comment: Are you able to use some other command?

Comment: I'm not sure but it may be related with some of environment variables. For example, `exec` drops `HOME` variable (http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/5224) which may be required by some commands. Just try to add `environment => 'HOME=/'` and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Slava's suggestion worked for me!

Vagrantfile:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = '2'

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'precise64'
  config.vm.box_url = 'http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box'

  config.vm.provision :shell do |shell|
    shell.inline = "mkdir -p /etc/puppet/modules;
                    puppet module install -f puppetlabs-stdlib;
                    puppet module install -f puppetlabs/apt"
  end

  config.vm.provision :puppet
end
```

manifests/default.pp:

```
# Update apt before installing any packages

class { "apt":
  update_timeout => 60
}

exec { "apt-update":
  command => "/usr/bin/apt-get update"
}

Exec["apt-update"] -> Package <| |>

package { "git":
  ensure => latest
}

package { "vim":
  ensure => latest
}

# Link vim profile

file { "/home/vagrant/.vimrc":
  ensure => link,
  target => "/vagrant/.vimrc",
  require => Package["vim"]
}

file { "/home/vagrant/.vim/":
  ensure => directory,
  owner => "vagrant",
  group => "vagrant",
  require => Package["vim"]
}

exec { "git vundle":
  command => "/usr/bin/sudo -u vagrant git clone https://github.com/gmarik/vundle.git /home/vagrant/.vim/bundle/vundle",
  require => [
    Package["git"],
    Package["vim"],
    File["/home/vagrant/.vimrc"],
    File["/home/vagrant/.vim/"]
  ]
}

# Install Vim packages

exec { "vundle":
  command => "/usr/bin/sudo -u vagrant /usr/bin/vim +BundleInstall +qall",
  environment => "HOME=/home/vagrant/",
  require => Exec["git vundle"]
}
```

.vimrc:

https://github.com/mcandre/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc

Answer (score 0):

You must provide a `cwd =>` entry, because the installation tries to go back to `cwd` between git clones, and got a permission denied. This is not logged. I found it when using https://github.com/jdevera/parallel-vundle-installer.